# Add set amount of items to an array JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to find how many `25` can fit into a number example  `100` should return `[25, 25, 25 ,25]`

At the moment I have this code

```
let quarterAmount = parseInt(argument / 25)
sum.push( 25 * quarterAmount )
```

However when I return the `sum` variable it will give me `[100]` instead of the desired array of `25`.
I have tried many variations of my code and I always get the same results

```
sum.push( '25' * quarterAmount )
```

```
sum.push( [25 * quarterAmount] )
```

```
sum.push( [25] * quarterAmount )
```

I want to be able to add `quarterAmount` amount of `[25]` to my array, how can I acomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```js
const howManyTimes = (a, b) => new Array(b/a).fill(a)

console.log(howManyTimes(25, 100))
```

`new Array(n)` creates an array with `n` items, then `fill` sets all the items to the same value.

Comment: This is a working solution, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The naive solution would be to make a loop like this:

```js
let quarterAmount = floor(argument / 25);
sum = [];
for (let i=0; i < quarterAmount; i++) {
    sum.push(25);
}
```

But there's a more convenient way of achieving what you want:

```js
let quarterAmount = floor(argument / 25);
sum = Array(quarterAmount).fill(25);
```

Here is the related documentation (about Array.fill):
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill

On a side note, I think you shouldn't use `parseInt`, but rather `floor`, `ceil` or `round`. `parseInt` will floor your value, but your intent is not to parse something, it is to round/floor/ceil something.

Comment: How can I accomplish this with 4 different amounts? say first it should be 25, then 10, and so on?

Comment: @imstupidpleasehelp I would suggest creating a function with two argument being the sum and the divider. Then, just replace "25" with your divider variable. You'll have to call this function for all your amounts.